# How to build from source Tensorflow Serving in Ubuntu - 20.04?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, tensorflow-serving

I wanted to build tensor-flow serving from source optimized for my cpu and I have followed the instructions given at [tensorflow serving page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup).

I felt like the instructions is not completed. I was only able to find these three lines of instructions and I have done it.

```
git clone -b r2.3 https://github.com/tensorflow/serving.git
cd serving
tools/run_in_docker.sh -d tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-devel \
                     bazel build --config=nativeopt tensorflow_serving/...
```

So I'm wondering what to do next after the last step? How can I install it in my ubuntu so that I can access it via terminal using the command like this `tensorflow_model_server --port=8500...`?

Answer (score 0):

After building Tensorflow Serving you can start testing it, a good starting point can be [this Serving Basic from Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_basic).